# dtype error in sklearn when fitting gammaregressor

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using `sklearn` to fit a Gamma regression. My `sklearn` version is `0.23.1`.
I am using the following line of codes

```
from sklearn.linear_model import GammaRegressor
mdl = GammaRegressor()
mdl.fit(X, y)
```

But I get the following error:

````
TypeError: check_array() got an unexpected keyword argument 'warn_on_dtype'```
````

Any ideas on why this happening?

Comment: Can you please add more code, what is the X and y that you're passing as input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs of the function which is running in the back you can find [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.check_array.html).

`By default, the input is checked to be a non-empty 2D array containing only finite values. If the dtype of the array is object, attempt converting to float, raising on failure.`

probably your `X`or `y`i is not a numeric object.

You should check `type(X)` and `type(y)` , probably you have an  `object`type.